# Continue Multiple span text merged in single span - XSLT

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

How to continued multiple `span`element the S/B merged in single `span` element.
**Input XML**

```
<root>
    <p>Paragraph <span>a</span><span>b</span><span>c</span><span>d</span> Under Continuing <span>Court</span> Jurisdiction</p>
    <p>Paragraph <span>a</span><span>b</span><span>c</span><span>d</span> Under Continuing Court <span>Jurisdiction</span></p>
</root>
```

**Expected Output**

```
<root>
    <p>Paragraph <span>abcd</span> Under Continuing <span>Court</span> Jurisdiction</p>
    <p>Paragraph <span>abcd</span> Under Continuing Court <span>Jurisdiction</span></p>
</root>
```

**XSLT Code**

```
        <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="span">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
        <xsl:for-each select="following-sibling::*[1][self::span]">
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Assuming you use an XSLT 2 processor look at any introduction into grouping using `for-each-group group-adjacent`, for instance the examples in https://stackoverflow.com/tags/xslt-grouping/info.

Comment: @MartinHonnen Sir, I am trying with `for-each-group group-adjacent` but not found any output. Can you chek my code where is the problem (https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/94AbWBr/2)

Comment: See the answer but next time consider to include your XSLT attempt in your question as well, not only as a link in a comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The template for `p` elements should be along the lines of

```
 <xsl:template match="p">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:for-each-group select="node()" group-adjacent=". instance of element(span)">
                <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="current-grouping-key()">
                        <span>
                            <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()/node()"/>
                        </span>
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:otherwise>
                        <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()"/>
                    </xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:choose>
            </xsl:for-each-group>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
```